# Already exist error in image data generator

Tags: tensorflow, image-processing, keras, anaconda, data-preprocessing

```
generator = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator(featurewise_center=False,
samplewise_center=False,
featurewise_std_normalization=False,
samplewise_std_normalization=False,
zca_whitening=False,
rotation_range=0,
width_shift_range=0.0,
height_shift_range=0.0,
brightness_range=None,
shear_range=0.0,
zoom_range=0.0,
channel_shift_range=0.0,
cval=0.0,
horizontal_flip=False,
vertical_flip=False,
rescale=1./255,
preprocessing_function=None,
data_format=None,
validation_split=0.0,
dtype=None)
```

I'm getting already exist error in this line. It only works base environment in anaconda. It doesn't work in other environments even though the required libraries are installed

Comment: Please add the actual error message as text in full.

Comment: This error could be due to TF and Keras versions mismatch. Please provide a full traceback of error along with the `TensorFlow version` installed in the environment where you are running this code to understand the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Having used the mentioned api with the latest dependencies won't help as [tf.keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/preprocessing/image/ImageDataGenerator) is not recommended for new code , being **Deprecated**.

Use the [tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/utils/image_dataset_from_directory) and transforming the output [tf.data.Dataset](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset) with preprocessing layers.

For more information, see the tutorials for loading images and augmenting images, as well as the preprocessing layer guide [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/load_data/images).